# How to select unique records from a result in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I am running a SQL query on oracle database.

```
SELECT   DISTINCT flow_id , COMPOSITE_NAME  FROM CUBE_INSTANCE where flow_id IN(200148,
200162);
```

I am getting below results as follow.

```
200162  ABCWS1
200148  ABCWS3
200162  ABCWS2
200148  OutputLog
200162  OutputLog
```

In this result 200162 came thrice as composite Name is different in each result. But my requirement is to get only one row of 200162 which is 1st one. If result contains same flow_id multiple times then it should only display result of first flow_id and ignore whatever it has in 2nd and 3rd.

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT - 

200162  ABCWS1
200148  ABCWS3
```

Could you please help me with modification of query?

Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: Define "first flow_id".  "first" implies some sort of ordering but you haven't told us what ordering you want.  Do you want the row where the `composite_name` comes first alphabetically?

Comment: Oracle data is _unordered_ in the table - as @JustinCave indicated, you will need to define some sort of sort order in your query. Also, the "DISTINCT" keyword applies to _all_ columns in your result set, not just the first one - each returned _row_ is unique, not just the first column value.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to take the lexicographically first composite name for each `flow_id`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY flow_id ORDER BY COMPOSITE_NAME) rn
    FROM CUBE_INSTANCE t
    WHERE flow_id IN (200148, 200162)
)

SELECT flow_id, COMPOSITE_NAME
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hello,
It is working fine but how to put everything in single query with select statement. I got confused with that.

Comment: Actually my answer already is a single query. If what you are asking is how to avoid using the CTE, just inline it: `SELECT flow_id, COMPOSITE_NAME FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() ... ) t WHERE rn = 1`

Comment: Thank you....!!! It is working as per my requirement...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "first" row, unless a column specifies that information.

But you can easily use aggregation for this purpose:

```
select ci.flow_id, min(ci.composite_name)
from cube_instance ci
where flow_id in (200148, 200162);
group by ci.flow_id
```

If you *do* have a column that specifies the ordering, you can still use aggregation.  The equivalent of the "first" function in Oracle is:

```
select ci.flow_id,
       min(ci.composite_name) keep (dense_rank first order by <ordering col>)
from cube_instance ci
where flow_id in (200148, 200162);
group by ci.flow_id
```